# Find linearization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\cos u-1+\mu
$$
and insert the traveling wave ansatz $u(x,t)=u(z), z=x-ct$. This gives
$$
-cu_z=u_{zz}+\cos u-1+\mu
$$
or, equivalently, the system
\begin{align}\tag{1}
&u_z=v\\
&v_z=-cv-\cos u+1-\mu.
\end{align}

What is the linearization of this system in $u=u_0$?

I think one makes the ansatz $u=u_0+w$ and gets
\begin{align}
&u_z=w_z=v\\
&v_z=-cv-\cos(u_0+w)+1-\mu
\end{align}

Now, how to linearize the term $\cos(u_0+w)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\cos(u_0+w)=\cos(u_0) \cos(w)-\sin(u_0) \sin(w)$ so:
$$\cos(u_0+w) = \cos(u_0) - \sin(u_0) w +O(|w|^2)$$
(Or even simpler $\cos$ is $C^1$ and $(\cos(u_0))'=-\sin(u_0)$).

Comment: The equilibria of the system (1) are $(0,u_0)$ with $\cos(u_0)=1-\mu$. Am I right that the linearization in the equilibria $(0,u_0)$ is given by $$\frac{d}{dz}\begin{pmatrix}w\\v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\sin(u_0) & -c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w\\v\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: It seems correct to me.